# Corona SDK - group with image rect, wrong reference point

Tags: coronasdk

I'm inserting a group of object into a parent group with image rect, and as far as I can understand, the excepted result should be that the outer group will start from top left point of the screen (0 ,0) and the group inside will refer to the top left point of the parent group, actually it is like I describe without having image rect in the outer group, the issue is when the outer group has an image rect inside so the outer group center point is at the top left point of the screen and the inner group is in the center of the parent group?

what is going on? please help...

```
local checkinContent = display.newGroup();
local BG= display.newImageRect(checkinContent,"images/magen-david_backgound.png",display.contentWidth, 0.45822 * display.contentHeight);

checkinContent:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint);
checkinContent.y = display.contentHeight - checkinContent.height;
checkinContent.x = 0;

local circlesGroup = display.newGroup();
circlesGroup:setReferencePoint(display.TopCenterReferencePoint);
circleTable[0] = display.newImageRect(circlesGroup,"images/circle.png",0.0265 * display.contentWidth, 0.0265 * display.contentWidth);
circleTable[1] = display.newImageRect(circlesGroup,"images/circle.png",0.0265 * display.contentWidth, 0.0265 * display.contentWidth);
circleTable[2] = display.newImageRect(circlesGroup,"images/circleCurrent.png",0.0265 * display.contentWidth, 0.0265 * display.contentWidth);

circlesGroup.y = 0;

checkinContent:insert(circlesGroup);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, sometimes corona is like walking in the dark...
here is a [video](http://masteringcoronasdk.com/corona-sdk-tutorial/display-object-reference-points-beginner/) with the answer..

the key sentence in the video is:

*" The weird thing is, as soon is this is created, and put in position, it's changes the reference point to the center... why?! I have no freaky idea.. "*

Answer (score 0):

Update these lines of code:

```
local circlesGroup = display.newGroup();
circleTable[0] = display.newImageRect(circlesGroup,"images/circle.png",0.0265 * display.contentWidth, 0.0265 * display.contentWidth);
circleTable[1] = display.newImageRect(circlesGroup,"images/circle.png",0.0265 * display.contentWidth, 0.0265 * display.contentWidth);
circleTable[2] = display.newImageRect(circlesGroup,"images/circleCurrent.png",0.0265 * display.contentWidth, 0.0265 * display.contentWidth);

checkinContent:insert(circlesGroup);
circlesGroup:setReferencePoint(display.TopCenterReferencePoint);
circlesGroup.y = 0;
```

Comment: If this dooesn't help then try to describe in a simple way what do you want to archive. It's hard to understand it from your explanation.

Comment: Thanks for you trying to help, you can see above that I've found my answer, the issue is that the reference point is changes to center after it is in his first position..